# Form sent but validation has error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My form is not working well. Although there's error, it's still able to go through. Errflag is 1 but it goes to the '0'. Appreciate if someone can shed some light.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rezasan/xxqtuc7d/

HTML

```
<form id="contact_form">
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <input type="hidden" name="sourcepage" value="Index Page">
        <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name" id="name" required />
        <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" name="email" id="email" required/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="TEL" name="phone" id="phone" required/>
        <select name="services" id="serviceslist">
          <option value="services" selected>SERVICES</option>
          <option value="botox">Botox</option>
          <option value="filler">Filler</option>
          <option value="Ultherapy">Ultherapy</option>
          <option value="coolsculpting">CoolSculpting</option>
          <option value="threadlift">Thread Lift</option>
          <option value="others">Others</option>
        </select>
        <div class="errtext"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <textarea rows="6" cols="55" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please enter your enquiries"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" style="float:right;" id="submit" name="submit" class="formelement-submit">
      </div>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function trimStr (str) {
      return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    }

    function checkTFieldValue(target,value,errorclass) {
      if(trimStr($(target).val()) == value) {
        $(target).addClass(errorclass);
        return 1;
      } else{
        return 0;
      }
    }

    function checkSFieldValue(target,value,errorclass) {
      if(value == "SERVICES") {
        $(target).addClass(errorclass);
        return 1;
      } else{
        return 0;
      }
    }

    function checkEmailValue(target,value,errorclass) {
      var err = 0;
      var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      if(trimStr($(target).val()) == value) {
        $(target).addClass(errorclass);
        err = 1;
      } else if(!emailReg.test($(target).val())) {
        $(target).addClass(errorclass);
        err = 1;
      }
      return err;
    }

    $('#contact_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="jsauth" value="dryga-f"/>');
    $('.formelement-submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      var errflag = 0;
      var counter = 0;
      $('.formerror').removeClass('formerror');
      $('.errtext').empty();
      var e = document.getElementById("serviceslist");
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

      errflag = checkTFieldValue('#name','','formerror');
      errflag = checkEmailValue('#email','','formerror');
      errflag = checkTFieldValue('#phone','','formerror');
      errflag = checkSFieldValue('#serviceslist',strUser,'formerror');
      errflag = checkTFieldValue('#message','','formerror');

      if(errflag == 1){
        $('.errtext').html('<p>*Please fill in all the required fields</p>');
      }
      if(errflag == 0){
        $('.errtext').html('No error');
      }
    });
```

Comment: TLDs have not been limited to 4 characters for years.

Comment: Yes, `errflag` gets changed to zero because you are assigning a new value five times in a row without any checks to see if it was already true.

Comment: `errflag` is overwritten for each validation call so a previous error state is ignored.

Comment: Okay I just realized. That's pretty dumb. How can I do it then sire? So that I can just check on one variable to sum up the whole form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `#message` is valid then it overwrites all others with `0`.

you need to `+=` the `errflag` and check for `>`:-

```
  errflag += checkTFieldValue('#name','','formerror');
  errflag += checkEmailValue('#email','','formerror');
  errflag += checkTFieldValue('#phone','','formerror');
  errflag += checkSFieldValue('#serviceslist',strUser,'formerror');
  errflag += checkTFieldValue('#message','','formerror');

  if(errflag > 0){
    $('.errtext').html('<p>*Please fill in all the required fields</p>');
  }
  else {
    $('.errtext').html('No error');
  }
```

also, as **@MarcoScabbiolo** suggests, use `submit` instead of `click`.

Comment: Many thanks BenG. You definitely saved my life! I totally missed out on the logic for that. I only thought that once it detected that errflag is 1, it won't continue. So I've been overwriting the errflag again and again which answers the problem. Thanks to @MarcoScabbiolo for your advise.

Answer (score 2):

When using forms, it's better to attach your validation handler into the form's submit event, not on the click of the submit button. Because there are other ways the form could submit, like pressing enter on an input.

Change

```
$('.formelement-submit').click(
```

To

```
$('#contact_form').on('submit',
```

It's working in [this fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/xxqtuc7d/1/)